# How do I get labels on Pie Chart Wedges in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, kendo-ui, pie-chart

http://jsfiddle.net/XPK3f/

I am looking to add the wedges of Pending Issued Closed actually on the wedges. 
I believe the changes need to be made in one of these objects.

```
seriesDefaults: 
    labels: 
        visible: true,
         template: "${value} ${category}",
series: 

    type: "pie",
    data: dataSet
```

Here is an example of how the series will have labels in the actual chart and not just on the legend. Please see the JSFIDDLE for details.

Thanks!

[pie chart http://www-958.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/manyeyes/images/pie-chart.gif?1292295884](http://www-958.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/manyeyes/images/pie-chart.gif?1292295884)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but yes, using a template inside the series-defaults labels, you can put pretty much whatever you need as the label.

```
seriesDefaults: {
    labels: {
        visible: true,
        template: "${category} - ${value} clients"
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XPK3f/2/

Comment: I was trying to get exactly on the wedges. Currently it is only around the wedges.

Comment: See documentation for series labels positions.  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.labels.position   Also updated jsfiddle using center positions.  http://jsfiddle.net/XPK3f/24/

Comment: Thanks, I'm no longer on this project, but I thought this might help someone else.